# Login to azure container

Tags: azure, azure-container-service

I used following quick start doc to spin up my first Azure container.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-quickstart#feedback

It worked fine. but how do I connect to container if I want to debug something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot connect to the container itself directly to debug, IE you can't SSH or RDP to it. Take a look at this graphic which highlights how a container differs from virtual machines:

[image: VMs vs Containers]

You can however pull logs from your container from the container engine. In your case you would want to use the following command in the Azure CLI: `az container logs`.

https://aka.ms/container_logs

Comment: Thanks for sending reference on VMs vs Containers. That gives an idea to me that if I want to get into container for any debugging reason, I can use "az container exec --exec-command "/bin/bash"" to get into the bash shell of container and look into the file system or run any python apps that I want to debug.

Comment: No problem! It is a weird concept to grasp at first, but once you do, you realize how powerful containers are! Please mark as answer if my response helped you =)

Answer (score 4):

When you invoke CLI through the Portal, you should already be connected through your subscription.To debug or troubleshoot you can look at the container logs. Check out this documentation for the exact commands
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-logs

Answer (score 1):

When I am building containers to run on ACI, I build them first in a local docker instance where they can be connected to and interactively debugged. When you're happy with how they run locally push them into ACI, and debug from the output logs if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I get to the bash shell in my Azure containers by either the azure-cli package, as the OP noted in a comment:

```
az container exec --exec-command "/bin/bash"
```

Or by navigating to a container instance in the Azure portal, then under Settings/Containers there is a "Connect" tab:

[image: Connection tab in an Azure container instance]